# Desplazar el cuerpo de la página a la derecha

Tags: css

Me preguntaba si existe alguna forma de hacer que el cuadro grande se pueda mover a la derecha de la página web sin que se ponga abajo del índice que hay a la izquierda (sin usar bootstrap).
Gracias por la ayuda :)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
.indice{
width: 12%;
border: solid;}
.cuerpo{
float: right;
width: 87%;
border: solid;}

<body>
    <h1>
        Centro formativo Lancaster
    </h1>

    <div class="indice">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="./informacion.html">Información del centro</a></li>
            <li><a href="./alumnos.html">Antiguos alumnos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cuerpo">
        <ul>
            <h2>Miembros del Centro</h2>
            <p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Directora: Jimena Álvarez Carrillo</li>
                    <li>Jefe de estudios: Gonzalo Menéndez Blanco</li>
                    <li>Coordinadora: Francisca Bonito Bonilla</li>
                    <li>Secretaría: Eduardo Pereira Gómez</li>
                </ul>
            </p>
        </ul>
        <hr>            
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ¿El cuadro donde dice miembros?

Comment: De paso por favor agrega tu CSS para poder replicar tu escenario

Comment: tienes algunos errores en el HTML. Tienes un `h2` y un parafo `p` dentro de una lista `ul`. Además de esto para que el `cuerpo` aparezca debajo del `indice` no tienes que hacer absolutamente nada. Si borras todo el css  que tienes los dos divs aparecen uno debajo de otro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay varias soluciones a este problema, si no quieres cambiar el layout y utilizar, por ejemplo, un contendor con display flex en modo fila, hay una solución algo más básica pero que consigue el objetivo:

```
.indice {
    max-width: 250px;
    float: left;
}

.cuerpo {
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Eso es, muchas gracias.Yo estaba haciendo es: `.indice{
    width: 12%;
    border: solid;
}

.cuerpo{
    float: right;
    width: 87%;
    border: solid;
}`

Comment: Esos detalles de tu código debieron ir en tu pregunta así sería mas fácil ayudarte @rabisa47

Comment: si, ya lo he agregado, lo siento. Es que no conseguía que me apareciera como código.

Answer (score 0):

Procedimiento

- Un contenedor general tanto para el menú del lado izquierdo como para el menú del lado derecho
- Al contenedor padre aplicarle la propiedad `flex` para hacer que todos los elementos queden alineados sobre el *main axis*
- Ahora a cada `div` que contienen a los menús les aplicaremos un ancho dado en porcentajes, dando la separación deseada considerando abarcar el 100% del viewport
- Por otro lado no hay razón para que una etiqueta de párrafo envuelva una lista de elementos desordenada
- Así como tampoco para que tengas un `hr` dibujando una línea, eso se puede hacer directo con CSS
- Finalmente el título hay que sacarlo y dejarlo dentro del `div` y no del `ul` como estaba antes

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .titulo-principal {
        background-color: steelblue;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .contenedor-menu {
        display: flex;
      }
      .indice {
        border: solid 1px ;
        width: 20%;
      }
      .indice > ul > li {
        list-style: none;
      }
      .cuerpo {
        border: solid 1px;
        width: 80%;
      }
    </style>
    <body>
    <h1 class="titulo-principal">
      Centro formativo Lancaster
    </h1>
    <section class="contenedor-menu">
        <div class="indice">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="./informacion.html">Información del centro</a></li>
                <li><a href="./alumnos.html">Antiguos alumnos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="cuerpo">
            <h2>Miembros del Centro</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Directora: Jimena Álvarez Carrillo</li>
                        <li>Jefe de estudios: Gonzalo Menéndez Blanco</li>
                        <li>Coordinadora: Francisca Bonito Bonilla</li>
                        <li>Secretaría: Eduardo Pereira Gómez</li>
                    </ul>           
        </div>
    </section>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: Ostras pues sí, es más cómodo. Esto me lo guardo y se lo voy a aplicar